# virtualbox: programmatically change resolution from inside guest

Tags: virtualbox, xrdp

I'm setting up a Linux VM that will be accessed via XRDP. The client user will only have access to the VM through RDP. I want him to be able to resize the guest but I haven't found a way to do that from inside the guest. How does one go about changing the guest resolution from inside the guest? I have guest additions installed but haven't been able to find any utilities that would help.

From the host you can run this:
VBoxManage controlvm "Arch Linux" setvideomodehint 1440 900 32

But, like I said earlier, the host will be inaccessible to the user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The user should have access to `xrandr` which will list the available video modes.  If the RDP client supports resizing after a connect, this should allow them to see the change immediately.  Otherwise the VM should retain the setting after disconnecting and reconnecting.  Running `xrandr` without any arguments will give a list of available resolutions available. Eg:

```
% xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024       0.0*
   1024x768        0.0
   800x600         0.0
   640x480         0.0
```

Then supplying a `-s n` parameter will set the resolution.  Eg. `xrandr -s 1` will set the resolution to 1024x768 in this example.

You can also add resolutions by using `setextradata` like this:

```
VBoxManage setextradata virtualmachine CustomVideoMode1 1120x986x32
```

Multiple modes / resolutions can be set by incrementing the 1 on the end.  Just be sure you have the guest additions installed otherwise this might not work as intended.